# How to find why my nodejs code can't stop?

Tags: node.js, process

I run a nodejs code but this code never stop and i can't find out why.

I use express and i close the server correctly with `server.close(error => ...);`. I use a MQTT client and i'm pretty i close it correctly too.

Is there a way to find and list actives threads ? And find what thread is blocking ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[why-is-node-running](https://www.npmjs.com/package/why-is-node-running) is what you are looking for. Hope this helps.